# Switch com varios POST

Tags: php, switch

tenho um duvida em relação ao Switch .

Quero colocar varias opçoes para um Switch e actualmente tenho assim e não funciona:

```
    if (isset($_POST['estado'])&& ($_POST['Distrito']))
{
switch($_POST['estado'] && $_POST['Distrito'])
{
case 'Indiferente'&&'Indiferente':
$sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
break;
case 'Indiferente'&&'Aveiro':
$sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id Where tb_trabalhador.Distrito = 'Aveiro' or 'AVEIRO' or 'aveiro' ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que você deseja não conheço nenhum método, mas com um pouco de criatividade (e gambiarra) há uma maneira.

```
switch ( [$_POST["estado"], $_POST["distrito"]] ) {
    case ['Indiferente', 'Indiferente']:
        // ...
    break;
    // ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: gambiarra, parte essencial do php

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o `switch` é indicado para validar o valor de uma **única** variável. Onde você pode ver assim

```
$var = 1;
switch ($var) {
    case 1: echo 'Um'; break;
    case 2: echo 'Dois'; break;
    ...
}
```

No seu caso realmente tem que ser as condições, onde você valida **vários** valores de uma mesma variável, como no caso do `$_POST` que é uma `Array`.

Porém você pode fazer um loop validando todas as chaves e assim poderia ser utilizado um switch.

```
$_POST = array('teste' => 'teste', 'teste1' => 'teste1', 'teste2' => 'teste2');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'teste': echo 'Testando'; break;
        case 'teste1': echo 'Testando novamente'; break;
        case 'teste2': echo 'Mais um teste'; break;
    }
}
```

Apesar de não indicar essa segunda forma pois ai você estaria fazendo uma interação com o array e validando com o switch, onde geralmente utilizamos mais de um valor de uma array para tratamento ou qualquer outra coisa.