# Resultado do Switch

Tags: php, switch

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET ['pagina'])) ? (int) $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
$where = "";
$estado = '' . @$_POST['estado'];
$distrito = '' . @$_POST['distrito'];
$concelho = '' . @$_POST['concelho'];

switch ([$estado, $distrito, $concelho]) {

    Case ['Indiferente', 'Indiferente', 'Indiferente']:
        break;
    case ['Indiferente', 'Aveiro', 'Indiferete']:
        $where = "WHERE tb_trabalhador.Distrito = 'Aveiro' ";
        break;
    case ['Indiferente', 'Aveiro', 'Agueda']:
        $where = "WHERE tb_trabalhador.distrito = 'Aveiro' AND tb_trabalhador.concelho = 'Agueda'";
        break;
}


//Aqui tenho a dúvida pois nem sempre quero utilizar $SQL. Se for ['autorizado','Indiferente','Indiferente'] Já tem uma query diferente. Como posso fazer essa distinção? 


$sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id $where order by tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) {
    echo "<table>";

    echo "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $exibe["Nome"] . "</td></tr>";

    echo "</table>";
}

$sqltotal = "SELECT id FROM tb_trabalhador $where";
$qrtotal = mysql_query($sqltotal) or die(mysql_error());
$numtotal = mysql_num_rows($qrtotal);
$totalpagina = ceil($numtotal / $quantidade);

echo '<a href="?pagina=1">Primeira página</a>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalpagina; $i++) {
    if ($i == $pagina)
        echo $i;
    else
        echo"<a href=\"?pagina=$i\">$i</a>";
}

echo '<a href="?pagina=$totalpagina">Ultima Pagina</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código todo? ou você tem certeza que é neste trecho que está dando o problema??

Comment: O problema e neste linha $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); ou seja depois de usar qualquer case da-me o problema.

Comment: Qualquer case está dando erro? As variáveis `$sql`e `$qr` existem fora dos cases?

Comment: da linha antes do While. Qualquer case dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Antes do `switch` tenta `var $sql, $qr;`

Comment: Com o var antes do Switch nem me mostra a pagina só o erro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode colocar código que não seja relativo ao `switch` dentro do `switch` porque isso é uma má prática de programação. Outra coisa é definir `$sql` antes mesmo de entrar no `switch`, porque nada garante que `$sql` vai ser definido dentro do `switch`.

O correto é usar desta forma:

```
$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET ['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
$sql = "";

if (isset($_POST['estado']) AND ($_POST['Distrito']) AND ($_POST['Concelho']))
{
    switch([$_POST['estado'] , $_POST['Distrito'], $_POST['Concelho']])
    {
        case ['Indiferente','Indiferente','Indiferente']:
            $sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
            $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            break;
        case ['Indiferente','Aveiro','Indiferente']:
            $sql = "(Query) asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
            $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            break;
        //(Varios cases)
    }

    $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
        echo "<table>"; 
        echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
        echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Se eu tiro o IF da-me erros.
Notice: Undefined index: estado
Notice: Undefined index: Ditrito
Notice: Undefined index: Concelho

Comment: Mas não é pra tirar o `if`. Apenas salientei o código que deve ser alterado. Vou mudar a resposta pra você.

Comment: E antes posso colocar a paginação? 
Ou tenho de colocar noutro local?

Comment: @user3253195 Pode sim.

Comment: Mas estou com um problema porque so me mostra os primeiros valores da query.
mostra-me o id1 e o id2 ja nao mostra.

Comment: @user3253195 Onde estão esses `id1` e `id2`? Editei a resposta novamente.

Comment: O id1 e id2 estão na base de dados mysql. isso será para mostrar os resultado de uma query de opçoes.
Quando eu peço para me mostrar a segunda pagina diz-me  Query was empty. Mas se eu testar o codigo no slq ja me mostra os dois resultados

Comment: Esta é uma pergunta clássica da série "desenvolvendo o aplicativo via Q&A" :)

Answer (score 3):

> Respondi aqui o que já tinha posto em uma [pergunta duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12045/paginacao-com-switch), e deletei a de lá.

Bom, o que eu percebo (olhando meio rápido) é que quando a pessoa muda de página, não existem mais as variáveis do `$_POST`, portanto a query não tem como executar.

Ou você muda de `POST` para `GET` e inclui nos links os dados da query, ou usa `POST` pra mudar de página também, ou vai precisar repensar esta lógica, seja usando variáveis de sessão ou alguma outra técnica para preservar os resultados.

Eis uma possível alternativa, usando `POST` para tudo. Note bem ao final, na parte da paginação, como os campos do form original foram repassados junto com a página desejada:

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_POST['pagina'])) ? (int)$_POST['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = $quantidade * $pagina - $quantidade;

$where = "";
$estado = ''.@$_POST['estado'];
$distrito = ''.@$_POST['distrito'];
$concelho = ''.@$_POST['concelho'];

switch([$estado, $distrito, $concelho])
{
   case ['Indiferente','Aveiro','Indiferente']:
      $where= "Where tb_trabalhador.Distrito = 'Aveiro'";
      break;

  case ['Indiferente','Aveiro','Agueda']:
      $where= "WHERE tb_trabalhador.Distrito = 'Aveiro' AND 
         tb_trabalhador.Concelho = 'Agueda'";
      break;
}

$sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on   tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id $where ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";

$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
   echo "<table>"; 
   echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
   echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";
} 

$sqltotal = "SELECT id FROM tb_trabalhador";
$qrtotal = mysql_query($sqltotal) or die(mysql_error());
$numtotal = mysql_num_rows($qrtotal);
$totalpagina = ceil ($numtotal/$quantidade);

echo '<form>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="estado" value="'.htmlentities($estado).'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="distrito" value="'.htmlentities($distrito).'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="concelho" value="'.htmlentities($concelho).'">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalpagina; $i++){
   if($i == $pagina)
      echo $i;
   else
   echo '<input type="submit" name="pagina" value="'.$i.'">';
}
echo '</form>';
?>
```

> Lembre de ajustar o form de origem pra usar o mesmo *casing* de caracteres no `name=""` dos inputs. Passei tudo para minúsculas.

Há outros problemas, como falta de otimização, e também no uso de funções inseguras `mysql_` em vez de `mysqli_`, mas uma pesquisa no SOpt ou na internet como um todo pode dar mais detalhes sobre isto.

Além disso você poderia ter um sql só, e incluir a condição `WHERE` de "Aveiro" como uma variável. E mais: se usar uma collation *case  insensitive* (o que geralmente é o padrão), o MySQL vai encontrar "Aveiro", "AvEiRo", "AVEIRO" da mesma forma.

Imagino que você esteja usando 1 como quantidade apenas para testes.

Outro detalhe: para contar os registros, basta usar `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela`, não precisa de `mysql_num_rows`.

De curiosidade, uma otimização para o código, se fosse pra ficar como está, que seria tirar o switch inteiro e deixar só essas duas linhas no lugar:

```
$where= $distrito=='aveiro'?" WHERE tb_trabalhador.Distrito = 'Aveiro' ":"";
$sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on   tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id $where ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
```

Comment: switch([$estado, $distrito, $concelho])
 {
 case ['Indiferente','Indiferente','Indiferente']:
 $where = "";
 break;

Não passa para a segunda pagina. 
A minha duvida é se a forma como estou a fazer utilizando o Switch é a melhor.

Comment: Acho que você precisava dominar um pouco mais a linguagem, pois não faz o mínimo sentido esse switch que você acrescentou (pelas explicações já dadas anteriormente). Do jeito que eu havia proposto, o switch ficaria só para quando tem where.

Comment: Seria legal pra você não confundir as coisas, tirar o switch todinho, deixar um sql só, e fazer a paginação funcionar. Sem swicth nenhum, como se fosse tudo indiferente. DEPOIS que funcionar, cuidamos do switch. Com certeza é uma coisa que dá pra resolver em 5 minutos, mas não aqui de longe e tentando adivinhar o que está havendo. Experimente resolver uma coisa por vez, tenho certeza que vai facilitar pra você.

Comment: Fiquei com um duvida apenas na forma que me disseste. é o seguinte Tenho varias querys dependendo do que o utilizador escolher. Vou alterar a minha pergunta a ver se me consegues explicar por alto uma forma

Comment: @user3253195 acertar a paginação primeiro seria melhor. A query é fácil consertar. Na verdade você aparentemente precisa de uma query só, e mudar só where, se eu entendi certo o "problema verdadeiro".

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei aqui devido a uma duplicata: [Switch com varios POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10748/switch-com-varios-post?rq=1)

Vou compartilhar algo que não vi em nenhuma resposta ou comentário.
É uma técnica mais flexível que permite estruturas condicionais:

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
switch(true)
{
    case ($foo > $bar):
        echo 'foo maior que bar';
    break;
    case ($foo < $bar):
        echo 'foo menor que bar';
    break;
    case ($foo == $bar):
        echo 'foo igual a bar';
    break;
}
```