# Paginação com Switch

Tags: php, paginação, switch

Onde escolho as opções:

```
  <span class="IWLABEL10CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Distrito</span>
  <select name="Distrito" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
 <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
 <option value="Aveiro">Aveiro</option>   
    </select>
    <span class="IWLABEL11CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Concelho</span>
   <select name="Concelho" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOCONCCSS" id="COMBOCID" tabindex="1">
  <option data-Distrito="Indiferente" value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>

<option data-Distrito="Aveiro" value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
     <option data-distrito="Aveiro" value="Agueda">Agueda</option>
 </select>

 <span class="IWLABEL4CSS" id="IWLABEL4">Estado</span>
  <select name="estado" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOFABCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
 <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
<option value="Autorizado">Autorizado</option>
<option value="Condicionado">Condicionado</option>
<option value="Nao Autorizado">Não Autorizado</option>
```

Onde faço a query:

```
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET ['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;

$sql ="";
if (isset($_POST['estado']) AND ($_POST['Distrito']) AND ($_POST['Concelho']))
{
    switch([$_POST['estado'] , $_POST['Distrito'], $_POST['Concelho']])
    {
    case ['Indiferente','Indiferente','Indiferente']:
        $sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on   tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio,     $quantidade";
        $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        break;

    case ['Indiferente','Aveiro','Indiferete']:
        $sql = "select * from tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id Where tb_trabalhador.Distrito = 'Aveiro' or 'AVEIRO' or 'aveiro' ORDER BY tb_trabalhador.id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
        $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        break;
    }
}

$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
    echo "<table>"; 
    echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
    echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";
} 

$sqltotal = "SELECT id FROM tb_trabalhador";
$qrtotal = mysql_query($sqltotal) or die(mysql_error());
$numtotal = mysql_num_rows($qrtotal);
$totalpagina = ceil ($numtotal/$quantidade);

echo '<a href="?pagina=1">Primeira página</a>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalpagina; $i++){
    if($i == $pagina)
        echo $i;
    else
        echo"<a href=\"?pagina=$i\">$i</a>";
}

echo '<a href="?pagina=$totalpagina">Ultima Pagina</a>';

?>
```

Estou com dificuldade ai porque só consigo ver os primeiros dados inseridos.

Comment: Coloquei conselho?

Comment: Não, está com 'c'. Mas eu sempre achei que fosse com 's'...

Comment: Ah, não . Concelhos são localidades em portugal.

Comment: @user3253195, por favor, [edit]e a pergunta para incluir mais informações e descrição do problema. Tal como dito na resposta abaixo, não está claro qual é o problema... O comentário que você fez ali deveria estar incluido aqui na própria pergunta. (ah, sim, na Galicia e Asturias também se usa Concelho nessa acepção :)

Answer (score 1):

Creio que ficou um pouco vaga a questão, já que não nos deu muito de sua regra de negócio a nível de fluxo. Porém pelo que pude perceber em uma análise rápida de seu código, quando faz uso da função `LIMIT`, em seu SQL, você passa duas variáveis como parâmetro.

Ao meu entendimento em relação à sua indagação da última linha, referente à conseguir ver apenas os primeiros dados inseridos, imagino que seja apenas uma pequena confusão com os valores que as variáveis `$inicio` e `$quantidade` estão assumindo em seu comando SQL. A `$quantidade` é apenas um armazenador estático para o valor `1`, pois não encontrei em seu código algum momento em que seu valor seja alterado.

Portanto, todo resultado de suas consultas apenas exibira **um** único registro. Portanto, como consequência de `$quantidade` ser estática, a `$inicio` se resume à `$pagina - $quantidade`, supondo que a sua verificação da variável `GET` esteja sempre retornando `1`, a execução do SQL traria sempre o registro `0`.

Comment: Eu quero que ele me mostre os dados todos do case ['Indiferente','Indiferente','Indiferente']: .. que tenho errado para alterar?

Comment: Por quê estais usando o LIMIT?